Given single observation, x, from a uniform distribution of 0 to N where 0 < N < 90 and N is uniformly distributed, what is the expected value of N?
In a physical system, an angle, $\theta$, is fixed but unobservable.  $\theta$ is restricted to the first quadrant, so $0 \le \theta \le90$. An angle, $\alpha$, lies between $0$ and $\theta$.  Only a single observation of $\alpha$ can be made.  Both $\theta$ and $\alpha$ are uniformly distributed.  What is the expected value of $\theta$ as a function of $\alpha$, $E[\theta](\alpha)$?
Although both $\alpha$ and $\theta$ are real, continuous variables, I believe this can be addressed considering discrete variables, since the measured quantities are always rounded to a limited number of significant digits.
I am aware of the German Tank Problem, which gives an answer of: $$E[\theta] = \alpha + \frac{\alpha}{k} - 1$$ for k observations.  This reduces to $E[\theta] = 2\alpha - 1$ for a single observation.  I believe that the - 1 in this equation comes from the fact that an observed tank means that there is at least one tank.  In the situation under consideration, where the lower bound is $0$, I believe the proper corresponding equation should be $E[\theta] = 2\alpha$.
However, in the German Tank Problem, there is no upper bound on the number of tanks that could be produced.
I am also aware of the argument that the probability of observing a specific value of $\alpha$ is highest when $\theta = \alpha$.
I believe the GTP applies when $\theta$ is much less than 90, but it does not make sense for the expected value of $\theta$ to be 2$\alpha$ if the result is greater than 90.  I think in the limit where $\theta$ approaches 90, it makes more sense for the expected value to be $\alpha$.
So, I believe that $E[\theta](\alpha)$ is a monotonically decreasing function which approaches $2\alpha$ when $\alpha \to 0$ and $\alpha$ when $\alpha \to 90$.
Is $E[\theta](\alpha)$ known?  What is the best way to approach this problem?

See the German Tank Problem.  That is usually phrased discretely, and it is usually assumed that you have more than one sample, but the ideas are relevant.

Try treating this as a conditional distribution question.  I think you can say the joint density is
$$f_{\Theta,A}(\theta, \alpha)=\frac1{90} \frac1{\theta}$$
for $0 \le \alpha \le \theta \le 90$, and $0$ otherwise.   That then gives you the conditional density
$$f_{\Theta\mid A}(\theta \mid \alpha)=\frac{f_{\Theta,A}(\theta, \alpha)}{\int_\alpha^{90}f_{\Theta,A}(\theta, \alpha)\, d\theta} = \frac1{\theta\, (\log_e(90)-\log_e(\alpha))}$$
for $0 \le \alpha \le \theta \le 90$, and then the conditional expectation
$$\mathbb E\left[\Theta \mid A=\alpha\right] = \int_\alpha^{90} \theta \,f_{\Theta\mid A}(\theta \mid \alpha)\, d\theta =  \frac{90-\alpha}{ \log_e(90)-\log_e(\alpha)}$$ for $0 \le \alpha \le 90$, which looks like

which is a lot more than $2\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is small and positive, but not far from $45+\frac{\alpha}2$ when $\alpha$ is close to $90$.

If $\theta$ is fixed then it is not a random variable but a parameter of the problem. In fact, $\alpha$ is a continuous uniform random variable in the interval $[0, \theta]$. The expected value of $\alpha$ is $E(\alpha) = \theta /2$. If $\theta \le 45$, $\hat\theta = 2 \, \alpha < 90$ is an unbiased estimator of the parameter $\theta$. A problem arises if $\theta > 45$. In this case $2 \, \alpha > 90$ with probability $(\theta - 45) / \theta$. To avoid this unphysical region of the parameter space we can correct the definition of the estimator:
$\hat\theta = \begin{cases}
2 \, \alpha \text{, if } \alpha \le 45 \\
90 \text{, if } \alpha > 45
\end{cases}$
The probability distribution of $\hat\theta$ can be calculated from the continuous uniform PDF of $\alpha$ is:
$f(\hat\theta) = \begin{cases}
\theta / 2  \text{, if } \hat\theta \le 90 \\
\frac{(\theta-45)}{\theta} \, \delta(\hat\theta-90) \text{, if } \theta = 90
\end{cases}$
The mean of $\hat\theta$ calculated from this distribution is:
$E(\hat\theta) = \begin{cases}
\theta \text{, if } \theta \le 45 \\
\frac{45}{\theta} \, (2\theta-45) \text{, if } \theta > 45
\end{cases}$
Therefore the $\hat\theta$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ only if $\theta < 45$ but it is not if $\theta > 45$. In the limit $\theta=90$, $E(\hat\theta) = 67.5$, a bias of $22.5$. I do not think you can do better than this...

It is true that for any given single observation, $\theta$ is fixed.  However, certainly the distribution of what $\theta$ might be is important.  For instance, if 90% of the time, $\theta$ is greater than 80, it would not make sense to have an expectation value of $2\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.  So, the answer must include knowledge of the distribution of $\theta$.

You might try simulating this.  Say take $10^6$ values of $\theta$ and for each one of those a value of $\alpha$.  Then take those values of $\alpha <5$ (slightly more than a fifth of all of them) and the average of the corresponding values of $\theta$ - I get over $22$, more than four times the $\alpha$s, so inconsistent with your $\hat \theta =2\alpha$ (if $\alpha<45$) being unbiased.

@Henry You are right. The problem is that the question states both that $\theta$ is a random variable and $\theta$ that is a fixed parameter. It cannot be both. If $\theta$ is a random variable, as the question development implies your solution is right (and very elegant too).  My solution would be applicable if $\theta$ is a fixed parameter.
